# push notification in blackberry webworks

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I need to implement the push notification in blackberry webworks I have successfully registered with blackberry and got mail with push notifications credentials. now what is the next step I found all the tutorials for native blackberry but not for phonegap how can I implement that in phonegap

any tutorials or sample application

Answer (score 0):

I can't just add comments yet so I'm adding an answer.
You can use the WebWorks Push API within a PhoneGap project https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.push.html

Comment: I followed the same link but I get the error result of function openbispush listener is not an function

Comment: Which version of the WebWorks SDK are you using to compile your app? (the version in the Eclipse SDK Plugin is outdated for the Push API)

Comment: I have resolved this issue. You need to add blackberry.push feature in config.xml and if your are using PhoneGap, call this function after deviceready is fired.